# How to get everything to the left from last delimiter in a string?

Tags: linux, string, sed, awk, cut

To cut last field in string I use:

```
command:         echo /dir1/dir2/dir3/file | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF; }'
output:          file
```

How can I get everything to the left from the last delimiter in the same string?

```
desired output:  /dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Thanks for you help

Rasty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bash` in itself is powerful enough to do this:

```
VAR="/dir1/dir2/dir3/file" echo ${VAR%/*}
```

Comment: This is the coolest one in my opinion as there's no need to use another command. It's only matter of variable and echo. THANKS!

Comment: you don't even need echo: `filename=${VAR##*/}; pathname=${VAR%/*}`

Comment: ssapkota & Glenn, you guys rock!

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with file names specifically, `dirname` and `basename` are the tools for the job:

```
pax$ dirname /dir1/dir2/dir3/file
/dir1/dir2/dir3

pax$ basename /dir1/dir2/dir3/file
file
```

For arbitrary delimiters, you can use `sed`:

```
pax$ echo /dir1/dir2/dir3/file | sed 's?/[^/]*$??'
/dir1/dir2/dir3

pax$ echo /dir1/dir2/dir3/file | sed 's?^.*/??'
file
```

The first replaces the sequence "slash followed by zero or more non-slashes to the end of the line" (`/file`) with nothing. The second replaces everything from the beginning of the line to the last slash (`/dir1/dir2/dir3/`) with nothing.

If you want the output of those commands assigned to variables, you can use `$()`:

```
pax$ filespec=$(basename /dir1/dir2/dir3/file) ; echo $filespec
file
```

Comment: Thanks for commands and explanation. With these commands I can cut any strings (not only paths). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the [dirname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirname) command.

```
> dirname /dir1/dir2/dir3/file
/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Just for completeness: [basename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly. I need directory in a filepath. THANKS! But still, how can the cut be done?

Comment: `VAR=/path/to/file/name; pathname=$(dirname "$VAR")`